# how to get database level roles into @preAuthorize method and <sec:authorise tag

Tags: spring-security

Actually i have roles in database like ROLE_USER,ROLE_MAKER,ROLE_CHECKER.now i am using method level restriction by mentioning @PreAutorize(hasRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_MAKER'),

Thanks in advance 
venu

Comment: This is my full Question......Actually i have roles in database like ROLE_USER,ROLE_MAKER,ROLE_CHECKER.now i am using method level restriction by mentioning @PreAutorize(hasRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_MAKER'),<sec:authorise access=hasRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_MAKER').
now in development it looks working,what if this application is used in production mode,where client created different role's like user,maker,checker,then the above mentioned scenario will not work,i feel this way is hardcoding,please suggest me idea's how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Check Permission Evaluator at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Step 1: Tell spring that you are going to use permission evaluator.

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.npacemo.permissions.SomePermissionsEvaluator"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Step2: Implement PermissionEvaluator at com.npacemo.permissions.SomePermissionsEvaluator

```
class SomePermissionsEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                      java.lang.Object targetDomainObject,
                      java.lang.Object permission){

if(permission.equals("check role")){
//ok I need to check for roles from DB..
if matching then return true else false..

    //write logic as per ur requirement

    }

boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                      java.io.Serializable targetId,
                      java.lang.String targetType,
                      java.lang.Object permission){

//write logic as per ur requirement
}

}
```

Step 3: call hasPermission inside PreAuthorize to check for ur roles

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#contact, 'check role')")
  public void deleteApplication(Contact contact);
```

Comment: I don't have permissions only some roles,i have to restrict some menus and editing the credentials if the logged in user don't have that role.can i use the same way as you mentioned.

Comment: ya..whatever you want to check can be think as permission because its determined at runtime...in the hasPermission you can check if for a particular user is allowed to carry away specified operation or not..

Comment: thanks for the information@Rajesh , i will work on that,but you didn't tell me how to hide menu <sec:authorise